# Isn't it obvious that $0$ and $1$ are distinct?

Tags: real-numbers, axioms

The field axioms for the real number system contain the following statements concerning the existence of neutral or identity elements for addition and multiplication:

(1) There exists a real number, called "zero" ($0$), such that, for all real $x,$    $x+0=0+x=x$, and
(2) There exists a real number, called "one" ($1$), such that $1\ne 0$ and, for all real $x,$ $x\cdot 1=1\cdot x=x$

Why is it necessary to include "$1\ne 0$" in (2) if we are calling these elements by different names?

Comment: Well, it's useful to establish that you can't have a field with exactly one element.  In principle $\{0\}$ could be a field.  After all, it has an identity element under addition and an identity under multiplication (as $0\times 0=0$).  It even has a multiplicative inverses!

Comment: The fact that we give these elements different names does not mean they are not the same. You can have two different names for the same objetc, this is not precluded by anything (for instance, modulo $2$ we have $0=2$). But as the answers point out, here we do want to enforce these two elements are actually distinct, so we say it explicitly.

Comment: @littleO We **do** explicitly assume (in the definition of a field) that $0\neq 1$, precisely because, as several people have pointed out in comments and answers, this **cannot** be proved from the other axioms. The other axioms hold in a one-element ring. (Of course, if we modified the other axioms cleverly, then we might be able to prove $0\neq1$ from the modified axioms; for example, it would suffice to add an axiom saying that a field has more than one element.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass oops, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it necessary to include "$1\ne 0$" in (2) if we are calling these elements by different names?

Because "calling these elements" by different names only does not necessarily imply that they are not the same. $\quad$

For instance, the zero ring is the (unique) ring in which the additive identity $0$ and multiplicative identity $1$ *coincide*.

---

[Added:] To elaborate the point above, suppose you have the following two axioms instead:
(a) There exists a real number, called "zero" ($0$), such that for all real $x,$    $x+0=0+x=x$, and
(b) There exists a real number, called "one" ($1$), such that for all real $x,$ $x\cdot 1=1\cdot x=x$.

Then the zero ring $\{0\}$ satisfies both (a) and (b), but you won't want a real number system like that.

Comment: Right, (1) asserts the existence of an additive identity and (2) asserts the existence of a multiplicative identity distinct from the additive identity in (1), but I'm still confused about the use of the symbols 0 and 1 in the _phrasing_ of (1) and (2). When reading "there exists an element 0 called 'zero' in R s.t. ..." what is the proper way to interpret this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. They are interpreted as what they are. Perhaps reading a bit of abstract ring theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory) might help you.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the symbols 0 and 1, when they first appear in the axioms, do not literally refer to the real numbers 0 and 1. They are merely symbols used to introduce the additive and multiplicative identities, right? Like, the axioms could be written: (1) "there exists a real number $\alpha$, s.t. $\alpha +x$..." and (2) "there exists a real number $\beta$ s.t. $\beta x$...$\alpha\ne\beta$" and of course we know that the real number 0 is the $\alpha$ element and the real number 1 is the $\beta$ element.

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise the "field" $\{0\}$, which is not a field regarding the definition with the usual axioms would be a field.

And it is not very practical to accept it as a field, so we usually demand $0\ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

1 is just the symbol for the unit element for multiplication

0 is the symbol for the unit element for addition

The elements could be the same, in fact, a trivial field {0} would have 0 = 1

Answer (score 0):

$1\ne 0$ because if not $1=0\Rightarrow a=0$ for all $a$. So simply as this.

"$1\ne 0$" is included because if not, after verification of $0\cdot a=0$ for all $a$ we would have as said above $a=0$ for all $a$.